Can we conclude joint convergence in distribution from marginal convergence in distribution for two (not independent) sequences of random variables?
Suppose we have two sequences of random variables $X_n$ and $Y_n$ defined on same probability space such that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges almost surely to $Y$. $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are not independent. $X$ and $Y$ are not independent as well. Can we conclude anything about the joint convergence in distribution of $(X_n, Y_n)$?
I know when both the sequences are independent, it's an established result. But the sequences are not independent. Another thing I tried to go for Skorohod representation of $X_n$ sequence. But in that case, we are moving to another probability space. So I guess that won't work well here. Any lead on this?

No, without independence the joint limit distribution is not determined

Yes, that's what I was thinking. Thank you.

A counterexample:
$X_n\sim N(0,1)$, $Y_n=(-1)^n(X_n)$.  Then for even $n$, $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in distribution to $(X,Y)$ with $Y=X\sim N(0,1)$ and for odd $n$ $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in distribution to $(X,-Y)$ with $Y=X\sim N(0,1)$, which are different distributions. So $(X_n, Y_n)$ doesn't converge in distribution.
What you do know is the $(X_n, Y_n)$ is uniformly tight, so every subsequence has a subsubsequence that converges in distribution.

Yes, I am familiar with this counter example. Will you please elaborate on the subsequence part if there's some hope to tackle that from this angle? Thank you in advance.

It depends on why you want convergence in distribution. For many purposes counterexamples like the one I gave don't really matter since you could just consider, say, the even $n$, and the tightness result says all the counterexamples in some sense look like that.
